# SQL Server index with condition

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-trigger

I have table `Range` with columns

```
Start (date), RangeTypeId (integer), ChannelId (integer), IsActive (bit)
```

I have this index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Range_Unique] 
ON [dbo].[Range] ([Start] ASC, [RangeTypeId] ASC, [ChannelId] ASC, [IsActive] ASC)
```

I want my index to prevent inserting or updating only in case of 2 rows with `IsActive = 1`. So I want index or some sort of trigger that will allow to have multiple `Ranges` with `IsActive = 0` and same start date, channel id and type, but only one with `IsActive = 1` and same start date, channel id and type.

Example of valid db table state:

```
Start | RangeTypeId | ChannelId | IsActive
------------------------------------------
23:00        5           1          0  
23:00        5           1          0  
23:00        5           1          0  
23:00        5           1          1
```

invalid:

```
Start | RangeTypeId | ChannelId | IsActive
------------------------------------------
23:00        5           1          0  
23:00        5           1          0  
23:00        5           1          1  
23:00        5           1          1
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a unique [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes) like so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [uIXf_Range_Unique] ON [dbo].[Range]
(
    [Start] ASC,
    [RangeTypeId] ASC,
    [ChannelId] ASC,
    [IsActive] ASC
)
where IsActive = 1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LBI81243

---

```
create table range ([Start] varchar(5), [RangeTypeId] int, [ChannelId] int, [IsActive] int) ; 
insert into range ([Start], [RangeTypeId], [ChannelId], [IsActive]) values
('23:00', 5, 1, 0),
('23:00', 5, 1, 0),
('23:00', 5, 1, 0),
('23:00', 5, 1, 1)
;
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [uIXf_Range_Unique] ON [dbo].[Range]
(
    [Start] ASC,
    [RangeTypeId] ASC,
    [ChannelId] ASC,
    [IsActive] ASC
)
where IsActive = 1
go
/* throws an error error due to duplicate key */
insert into range ([Start], [RangeTypeId], [ChannelId], [IsActive]) values
('23:00', 5, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,There is one big disadvantage of `UNIQUE FILTERED INDEX` .

Main purpose of index is to speed up select query.
So it is possible that above index are not utilize in most of the select query,in that case  we often  change index .

So main purpose of index is defeated.In that case we drop the index and create index on some other column/columns.

Idea of `Filtered index` is also different than use here.Purpose of filtered index is that if among huge data,we query on certain value very frequently then we create filtered index on that column using that value like above.Its purpose is not to provide uniqueness.

Suppose DBA is not aware of this plan and DBA decide to drop this index then you may start getting duplicate records.

So best way to check duplicate in this case will be to check via code .

```
if not exists (select id from mytable where [Start]=@Start and  [RangeTypeId]=@RangeTypeId
    and  [ChannelId]=@ChannelId and [IsActive]=1)
    BEGIN
    print 'insert'
    END
```

If  insert/update can happen from several places then it is wise to use trigger.